# Activate profiles in maven sub modules

Tags: maven

I have the following multi-module maven project:

```
build
 -> build-common
 -> build-a
 -> build-b
```

In **build-a** and **build-b** I have a profile called **myDeploy**. Now I would like to build the parent project from commandline but only activate **myDeploy** for eg. subproject **build-b**. Is this possible?

Alternatively I could rename the profiles for each subproject to **myDeploy-a** and **myDeploy-b**.

Comment: Why do you need such an profile? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: So I can use the same scm url for multiple jenkins jobs and only specify different command line args for maven.

Comment: Are you talking about the SCM url in the pom file? If so no need for this. Only in the parent module and never in sub modules at all.

Comment: Sorry, no the scm url (git/svn ...) specified on jenkins.

Comment: If you would like to do checkout via Jenkins you have to give the correct URL/Git repos to let jenkins do it's job ..so can you elaborate a little bit more what you like to achieve ?